# How to use the existing SQLite database in my local to retrieve values in WP 8 emulator?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

> Object reference error

in below part (it couldn't find my local DB file 1st, in order to copy). Db file is inside my project folder - Assets ; Properties window, have set the Build action to Content.

```
StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("people.sqlite");

await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask good questions. This one seems to be lacking some important details, also please look at: [What is a NullReferenceException and how to fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [Application.GetResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms596994(v=vs.105).aspx).

*"Returns a resource file from a location in the application package.*

The `GetResourceStream` method enables you to load resource files with Content or Resource set as the Build Action property value."

[This](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone) is for WP8 but should explain the process.